# Display text in UITextView from .docx

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsstring, type-conversion

I want to display in my `UITextView` a .docx. It is impossible without external libraries (that I can't found). So I tried to convert (.docx converted in .pdf) a .pdf into a .rft and put it into an `UITextView`:

```
let rtf = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("2", withExtension: "rtf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)      

let attributed = try NSAttributedString(fileURL: rtf, options:[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)

textView.attributedText = attributed
```

It works, the .rtf file is displayed into the `UITextView`. But the process of converting the pdf don't keep all the information they bend it, if I manually do copy and paste. If I use an app to convert from bad to worse.

So what is the best way to proceed ?

Example of the same part of text in .pdf and .rtf:

PDF File
[image]

RTF File

[image]

Comment: Do you need your users to edit the documenting the UITextView or just view it? If you only need to view the PDF then use UIWebView.

Comment: The user doesn't need to view the PDF. But i want a more beautiful look. To improve the ease of study this document.

Comment: So to clarify, they do NOT need to edit the document, just view it?

Comment: They NOT need to edit the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to view the document, you should view it as a PDF in a UIWebView. This will maintain all your formatting and provide the best user experience:

In your view controller you will have a web view defined. Here is an example connected via Storyboard:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!
```

And then you can load the PDF this way:

```
let pdf = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("2", withExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: pdf)
webview.loadRequest(request)
// You might want to scale the page to fit
webview.scalesPageToFit = true
```

Comment: I don't wanna use UIWebView. The best UX is to display text in the UITextView

Comment: Well, you know your users needs the best, but in iOS the best way to preserve formatting for user display is UIWebView with PDF or HTML. If you keep trying to go the route of DOCX->PDF->RTF you will only lose formatting.

Comment: There has to be another way.

Comment: Not to discourage you, but you won't find a good way to put it as attributed text in a UITextView and have it render the same as a PDF. This is the entire reason for the PDF format so that you get accurate rendering of a document. I think the best you can do is try another converter for DOCX to RTF, but not matter what you do, moving to RTF will lose some formatting.

Comment: I have same problem. I have to download .docx file from server and show it's text into UITextView and user will also able to edit it. I have found SNDocx library but it sometime not work as expected. Any suggestion will welcome.